# How to get the version of mongodb from php

Tags: php, mongodb

I need a way to display a version of Mongo database in the php website.
For example, I want to show something like "powered by MongoDB version 2.2.6"

I cannot find a way to find out the version of database that php mongoClient is connected to.

I'm sure that is a way to do this. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mongo = new \Mongo();

$admin = $mongo->admin;

$infos= $admin->command(array('buildinfo'=>true));
$version = $infos['version'];

die($version);
```

(You need to be admin to show it)

UPDATE : Without authentication, you can check it by using a MongoDB instance.

```
$c = new \MongoClient();
$db = 'yourdbname';

$mongo = new \MongoDB($c, $db);

$mongodb_info = $mongo->command(array('serverStatus'=>true));
$mongodb_version = $mongodb_info['version'];

die($mongodb_version);
```

Comment: I think when a website runs in production the credentials used for connecting are not the admin user but regular user. I want to be able to show the "powered by" notice on regular php generated pages, so it will not be the admin in the MongoClient connection

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `serverStatus` command:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/

If you're using the PHP driver, check out:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php

to see how you can run that command.

Comment: Any way to do this from php and get result in php script?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, maybe this:

```
<?php
$v = `mongo --version`;
print_r($v);
?>
```

Comment: this is not a general solution. It works only if the mongo db is installed locally and your script has the permission to execute commands

Answer (score 0):

```
$server_status = db->command(array('serverStatus' => TRUE));
```

will give you lots of information including version
(you need to be admin to run it)